# Form submit button onclick does not call my JS function included in JS file

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html form with a submit button. I have a js function in a file that I include in the head. I am trying to bind the onclick event of the button to call that function. However, all the methods I tried did not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script src="popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <button type="button" onclick="displayFormContents();">
</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" >
<br>
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" >
<br>

<form>
    age : <input type="date" name="Age">
</form>

<form>
    Phone : <input type="number" name="Phone">
</form>

<form>
    email : <input type="email" name="mail">
</form>

<form>
    Student at UCLA? : <input type="checkbox" name="Doe">
</form>

<form>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</form>

<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You misuse the `form` tag. You should have a single one for the set of your inputs. You should also show the js file.

Comment: Do what @davidxxx says. Use a single ```<form>``` tag for all the contents you want to be inside the form. And call the function upon an ```onSubmit()``` event.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have created displayFormContents() method in popup.js file.Then there is no need to use form tag multiple times.Put your all form elements inside one form tag.

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form>
<p id="demo"></p>
 First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" >
  <br>
  Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="name" >
  <br>
  age :
  <input type="date" name="Age">
  Phone :
  <input type="number" name="Phone">
  email :
  <input type="email" name="mail">
  Student at UCLA? :

  <input type="checkbox" name="Doe">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>

  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>

  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other

<button type="button"
onClick="displayFormContents();">Submit
</button>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A single form is the correct solution. I'm wondering if the OP is trying to only save what has been changed. A bit more advanced, but as a note research ajax, I'd recommend [jquery](https://jquery.com/) and [jquery ui](https://jqueryui.com/) to complement it.

Answer (score 0):

Use only a single form tag. popup.js should be in the same folder as the file containing this code. popup.js should have displayFormContents() function. Call the function on form submit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="displayFormContents()">
<p id="demo"></p>
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" >
<br>
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" >
<br>
    age : <input type="date" name="Age">
    Phone : <input type="number" name="Phone">
    email : <input type="email" name="mail">
    Student at UCLA? : <input type="checkbox" name="Doe">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```